# Network Manager blocked result in hang system

Tags: 18.04, network-manager

I've encounter this problem, which hangs the operational use of my OS as such.
- Not able to sudo, su -, launch a new terminal 
- Not able to reboot (cli or gui)
- No network
- Not able to launch new apps
- Existing Apps able to work, e.g. text editor running can still save a file.

Dmesg and Kernel logs last indicating before the issue had occured are as below:

```
Aug 20 23:19:34 T303UA kernel: [ 2054.916825] INFO: task NetworkManager:1331 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
Aug 20 23:19:34 T303UA kernel: [ 2054.916843]       Tainted: G           OE    4.15.0-32-generic #35-Ubuntu
Aug 20 23:19:34 T303UA kernel: [ 2054.916849] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
Aug 20 23:19:34 T303UA kernel: [ 2054.916858] NetworkManager  D    0  1331      1 0x00000000
Aug 20 23:19:34 T303UA kernel: [ 2054.916867] Call Trace:
Aug 20 23:19:34 T303UA kernel: [ 2054.916886]  __schedule+0x291/0x8a0
Aug 20 23:19:34 T303UA kernel: [ 2054.916895]  schedule+0x2c/0x80
Aug 20 23:19:34 T303UA kernel: [ 2054.916903]  schedule_preempt_disabled+0xe/0x10
Aug 20 23:19:34 T303UA kernel: [ 2054.916910]  __mutex_lock.isra.2+0x18c/0x4d0
Aug 20 23:19:34 T303UA kernel: [ 2054.916922]  ? futex_wait+0xed/0x250
Aug 20 23:19:34 T303UA kernel: [ 2054.916931]  __mutex_lock_slowpath+0x13/0x20
Aug 20 23:19:34 T303UA kernel: [ 2054.916937]  ? __mutex_lock_slowpath+0x13/0x20
Aug 20 23:19:34 T303UA kernel: [ 2054.916944]  mutex_lock+0x2f/0x40
Aug 20 23:19:34 T303UA kernel: [ 2054.916954]  rtnl_lock+0x15/0x20
Aug 20 23:19:34 T303UA kernel: [ 2054.916962]  ip6mr_sk_done+0x33/0xd0
Aug 20 23:19:34 T303UA kernel: [ 2054.916973]  rawv6_close+0x1d/0x40
Aug 20 23:19:34 T303UA kernel: [ 2054.916982]  inet_release+0x42/0x70
Aug 20 23:19:34 T303UA kernel: [ 2054.916989]  inet6_release+0x30/0x40
Aug 20 23:19:34 T303UA kernel: [ 2054.916997]  sock_release+0x25/0x80
Aug 20 23:19:34 T303UA kernel: [ 2054.917005]  sock_close+0x12/0x20
Aug 20 23:19:34 T303UA kernel: [ 2054.917014]  __fput+0xea/0x220
Aug 20 23:19:34 T303UA kernel: [ 2054.917022]  ____fput+0xe/0x10
Aug 20 23:19:34 T303UA kernel: [ 2054.917032]  task_work_run+0x9d/0xc0
Aug 20 23:19:34 T303UA kernel: [ 2054.917042]  exit_to_usermode_loop+0xc0/0xd0
Aug 20 23:19:34 T303UA kernel: [ 2054.917051]  do_syscall_64+0x115/0x130
Aug 20 23:19:34 T303UA kernel: [ 2054.917060]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x3d/0xa2
Aug 20 23:19:34 T303UA kernel: [ 2054.917068] RIP: 0033:0x7f5998480447
Aug 20 23:19:34 T303UA kernel: [ 2054.917073] RSP: 002b:00007ffc768f5d40 EFLAGS: 00000293 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000003
Aug 20 23:19:34 T303UA kernel: [ 2054.917080] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: 0000000000000013 RCX: 00007f5998480447
Aug 20 23:19:34 T303UA kernel: [ 2054.917084] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 00007f5998469c58 RDI: 0000000000000013
Aug 20 23:19:34 T303UA kernel: [ 2054.917088] RBP: 000055ffae02f440 R08: 000055ffae02f440 R09: 0000000000000010
Aug 20 23:19:34 T303UA kernel: [ 2054.917092] R10: 000000000000003d R11: 0000000000000293 R12: 000055ffae02f448
Aug 20 23:19:34 T303UA kernel: [ 2054.917096] R13: 000055ffae02f450 R14: 00007f599a1a3200 R15: 000055ffadfe2f60
```

System Info:

- Ubuntu 18.04
- Linux T303UA 4.15.0-33-generic #36-Ubuntu SMP Wed Aug 15 16:00:05 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
- Hardware, asus transformer 3 pro t303ua

Help appreciated.

Comment: This kind of issue often result into a hardware RAM fault.

Comment: So you think it is an device / hardware issue?

Comment: I'm afraid, but to be sure, do you have a way to check with a live CD and run from it few hours to check if you have a similar issue? This may also coming from a faulty network card or buggy drivers. Does your system work fine before?

Comment: As I recalled, when I first install and ran 18.04, it was perfectly fine (home or at work). Until recently, the issue hits when I uses either the Asus Universal-Dock or realtek USB dongle.  At work use a J5create usb-c hub , it was fine. All drivers are "off the shelf", I did not have to specially install any other driver for me to make any of my peripherals work.

Comment: Are you getting the issue only with one of those USB network adapter?

Comment: I'm getting issues out 2 out of 3 network adapters(aside wireless). 
The j5create usb-c works fine and so is wireless.

Comment: fwiw I have a new Lenovo X1 Carbon and a USB Ethernet dongle, and I'm seeing `NetworkManager` freeze up with a "Ds" status from `ps`, and otherwise very similar behavior. The machine has built-in Intel Ethernet too but I won't get the adapter for it until later today; maybe that'll help.

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue with a Dell XPS 13, both Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04, and a SBVR USB-c adapter for ethernet + HDMI. Does the problem still not occur for the J5create dongle?

Comment: Same issue KUbuntu 20.04 with a Dell USB-C to USB-A 3.0 adapter

Operating System: Kubuntu 20.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.18.5
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.68.0
Qt Version: 5.12.8
Kernel Version: 5.4.0-52-generic
OS Type: 64-bit
Processors: 8 × Intel® Core™ i7-10510U CPU @ 1.80GHz
Memory: 15.3 GiB of RAM